# iOS Xcode: UIButton titleLabel color keeps changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Scenario = I have a UIButton with a titleLable (text) on it that's characteristics will change depending upon if a boolean value is YES or NO. I set that button's titleLabel textColor to white in storyboards. Now, programmatically, if the boolean value is set to NO, I would like that color to change to red.

All of this works fine.

Problem = When I tap the button after it has been set to red, upon lifting of my finger, the titleLabel on the button changes *back* to white.

Question = How can I set the color of my titleLabel to the right color and keep it the correct color throughout the duration of the boolean variable's state?

```
//CODE
//Button text set to 'white' in storyboard


if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"bool"]==YES) {

    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue"]];

}

else {

    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red"]];

}
```

Order of Fubar goes like this...

```
1 drag UIButton onto view controller
2 set UIButton titleLabel textColor to white (storyboards)
3 in view controller .m viewDidLoad I type the code above
4 I run the program on my iPhone
5 press button (bool = NO and textColor is red)
6 (.00000000001 seconds after #5) I lift my finger from the button and the titleLabel textColor changes back to the white color that is set to in storyboard.
7 frustration ensues
```

Comment: Could you post some code that you've tried so far? It's hard to tell you what's wrong when we don't know what you've tried...

Comment: button.titleLable.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; --- it changes to red, but upon launching the application and pressing the button, the button changes back to white on the touch.

Comment: I meant some code like: Where are you changing the boolean? Where are you checking the boolean? Where are you setting the colors? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `self.button.titleLabel.text = ...`

try

`[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:-

```
[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // You can add whatever color you like.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3

**Using System Color**

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

**Using with RGB Color**

```
btnLogin.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(red: (100.0/255.0), green: (150.0/255.0), blue: (200.0/255.0), alpha: 1), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

## Objective-c

**Using System Color**

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Using with RGB Color**

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(100.0/255.0) green:(150.0/255.0) blue:(200.0/255.0) alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```